# JHipster Gateway and Microservice Translation not found

Tags: translation, jhipster, microservices

I have a gateway for a microservice, both builded with jhipster.

If I put some restriction for roles to the api, the front show a message saying that the traslation not found.

I added the traslation to all the global.json and nothing.

[image: .]

Update:

I'm trying with a monolith Application and the result is the same.

I'm using the CustomParameterizedException to throw excepciones from the services and nothing, the message is the same. Translation not found

Comment: It seems like a permission problem; check file permissions.

Comment: It's weird because the translation for error.internalServerError works well... I guess that is not an file permisiones problems.